# How to change max attributes in Weka?

Tags: java, nlp, weka

I am using Weka to create a Term Document Matrix using the class **StringToWordVector**. However, irrespective of the size of the input corpus I can see only 500 Terms/"num attributes" in output while the same corpus is generating 549 Terms when I use the R **tm** package.

I tried changing the **wordsToKeep** setting but that is not affecting the total number of terms generated. To me it seems there is some default setting that I need to change to increase the terms generated. However, I did not found such a configuration.

I am using Weka 3.6.11 and the NGramTokenizer.

How do I make Weka generate more Terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Weka 3.7.11 and tried this and it worked.

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector(); 
filter.setWordsToKeep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```